# Lapply dislikes my function

Tags: r, sapply

I've written a simple function to find the mean of two columns

```
mean_Response <- function(x, colnum, colnum2){
     x[,colnum]+x[,colnum2]) / 2
     }
```

nothing fancy. this works fine when I call it on my table, "maths" but fails on lapply

when I run it directly I get a fine result

```
maths$mean_answer <- mean_Response(maths, 12,30)
```

works a charm but

```
lapply(maths,mean_Response, 12, 30)
```

gets

```
Error in x[, colnum] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

similarly if I attempt to write it as an anonymous function in lapply it also fails

```
mean_Response <- sapply(maths, function(x){x[,12]+x[,30]/2})
```

I feel like I've missed something basic here in my sapply understanding but I can't quite figure out what it is given that I thought you were supposed to be able to pass things this way.

I've seen in other questions that perhaps this might be due to the way sapply interacts with vectors, but I'm not totally sure I get why it would understand functions in some areas and not others.

I'm not looking for a solution so much as more information on understanding how sapply is working here if that makes sense (this is a learning exercise not a 'please fix it for me' exercise, although hints on how to fix it are welcome)

Comment: `lapply` will loop over each column of `maths`, which means you are trying to select a column of a column, which isn't the right dimension.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? `lapply` is designed to call a function for each element of a "collection" (vector, list, ...). `maths` is no list. You could make a list with one element: `lapply(list(maths),mean_Response, 12, 30)`, whcih would be the same as calling the function directly like in your example.

Comment: Both of these are v helpful, thank you; @thelatemail I suppose that's why it works on a list but not a data table? AEF I take it what you're saying is that for it to work on a list you have to break the data table down into a collection of lists then loop over the respective elements, correct?